# Using (Scala) library from Java Web App, getting NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, maven, akka

I've been working on a rather "standard" Java web application for a long time now. I develop in Eclipse using Eclipse's server plugin to run the app in Tomcat. The app's setup is straight forward: Spring for bootstrapping, Wicket for web, Hibernate for ORM, Maven for dependency management.

Today I have added Akka 2.0 to the project. I added it to my POM as per the manual:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
<artifactId>akka-actor</artifactId>
<version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Maven finds the dependency and I can see it showing up in the Maven dependencies in Eclipse's package explorer. The referenced Scala Library also shows up (version 2.9.2 as it seems).

I can use the library just as one would expect: Eclipse finds the classes, I can jump to source files etc. Everything works perfectly. But once I start the app and it comes across any part of the program with references to Akka it throws a NoClassDefFoundError.

Since all other libraries still work as expected, my best guess is that is has something to do with the fact that Akka is a library developed in Scala. Since I've hardly used Scala myself though, I could not find any solution to the issue myself and Google isn't really that helpful when it comes to such generic exceptions.

Do you have any advice?

Comment: I am unfortunately terribly bad at guessing what actual class is missing when someone says "NoClassDefFoundError", if the full trace of such an exception was provided, surely more people would be able to answer your question. Thank you

Comment: It's any class really. When I tried to create an ActorSystem during start-up it would be akka.actor.ActorSystem, if I'd create anything on the fly it could be akka.util.Duration. My guess is that nothing from the library is found at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that the required library (AKKA) is in your deployment assembly under Eclipse: open the project's properties and look for "Deployment Assembly" on the left.

[I'm using Eclipse Indigo]

You could verify the presence (or lack) of the expected jar file by examining the deployment under tomcat.

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. Although it still leaves me wondering: I've never (knowingly) used this pane before and it always worked. Now I simply added the Maven Dependencies and it worked...but it's weird. Anyhow, thanks a lot!

Comment: I can't say for sure, but it's possible if you had done "Maven --> Update Project" (right-click on project), then Maven might have done that for you.